# Sum up a column based on multiple column matches (some partial)

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file like below.

```
7404920998 May 18 04:22 20161229.data
8775804219 May 18 04:23 20161230.data
11168788265 May 17 22:07 20170103.data
9374414428 May 17 22:03 20170104.data
```

I wanna sum up column 1 based on matching fields column2 (month) and first four characters of column5 (year). Then print an array out for each month and year.

Output:

```
16180725217 May 2016
20543202693 May 2017
```

I believe I figured out how to sum up by month and year by passing input

```
awk '{if($2 == "<month>" && $5 ~ /<year>/) i+=$1} END {print i, $2, substr($5, 0, 4)}' <file>
```

But how do I create a conditional array that matches these two conditions and prints out the output I desire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk   '{a[$2 FS substr($5,1,4)]+=$1} 
     END {for(k in a) print a[k],k}' file | sort -k3n -k2,2M

16180725217 May 2016
20543202693 May 2017
```